# How to group and combine subdoc arrays with mongo aggregation pipeline

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Envision a collection that returns an array of documents with this structure on the $match operator of the aggregation

```
A = {
  slug:'a',
  Rs:[{
    _id:'foo',
    attr2:'bar'
  }]
}
```

So basically each document returned, shares a slug (that's how i will group them) but each document has an array of subdocs each with a different _id.

So when I perform a $match aggregation with {slug:"a"} it returns an array of `[A0,A1,A2...]` etc where they all share the same slug. I'm calling each doc A

Next in the pipeline I group them and want to see their Rs arrays

```
{
 $group:{
    _id:'$slug',
    arrays:{$push:'$rs'}
  } 
}
```

This returns a single document that looks like this

```
{
  _id:"a",
  arrays: [
  [{_id:'foo',attr2:'bar'},{_id:'foo2',attr2:'beer'}], //The arrays of document A0
  [*A1 arrays*], //the arrays of document A1
  [*A2 arrays*]
  ]
}
```

So this is grouping all my documents into one and giving their subdoc arrays as sub-arrays in my grouped document which is an array of arrays `arrays:[[A0Rs0,A0Rs1],[A1Rs0,A1Rs1],[A2Rs0,etc]]`

My overall goal is to concat or flatten these arrays so instead of having an array of arrays I have a single array with all the values, and I would ideally like to do this using the aggregation operators. So instead of ending up with an array of arrays as above, i would end up with

```
{
 _id:"a",
 arrays:[
   {},{},{}... //all of the arrays. In fact these dont even have to be objects, I am after just the ID field of each object
 ]
}
```

I have tried a combination of $concatArrays and other operators, not sure if I need to add other steps or aggregators before my $group or how to approach this.

I hope I wasn't too confusing in my explanation, if anyone can think of a way to do this I'd really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested in knowing one way to get to the right solution, as im sure there's more than one, I managed to get the result i was looking for by using a combination of operators, starting with $unwind.

$unwind basically separates your parent document (the one with the array) into multiple documents, one per element in the array. IT does that for all your results, so now instead of having multiple objects with array of subdocuments, you just have multple documents with a single subdocument. You can then use $match and $group so in the end you get a single array with all the results you want. You can also use $project to reduce the number of fields in your documents if you're only after one array like me in this scenario.